# How to implement this model in Django?

Tags: python, django-models

I am new to Django and I getting some difficulties in implementing this model in Django:

[image]

Until now I have the model working without the table "Positions", and looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Category(models.Model):
    n_category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Directory(models.Model):
    website_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    website_url = models.URLField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

My question is, How can I add the table "Positions" to this model?

Please give me a clue.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a the model `Position` which has ForeignKeys to `Categories` and `Directory` and all the other data needed. And then use the `through` argument for the ManyToManyField. This is described in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)

Example (which if haven't tested):

```
class Position(models.Model):
    website_postiton = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    directory = models.ForeignKey('Directory')

class Category(models.Model):
    n_category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Directory(models.Model):
    website_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    website_url = models.URLField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through=Position)
```